# Open file in external browser using `helm-for-files`?

Tags: emacs, emacs-helm

I would like to search for a file with `helm-find-files` and then open this file externally with my default system browser (Chrome). The command `helm-ff-run-open-file-externally`, invoked with `C-c C-x`, prompts me for an option. But none of the candidates look like the name of my browser. Am I missing the right candidate, or am I using the wrong command?

For context: the file I am trying to open is a .gdoc file, i.e. a reference to an external Google Doc. In Dired, I can open it by invoking `browse-url-of-dired-file`.

Answer (score 0):

The "helm-ff-run-open-file-externally" command is not the right command to use for opening a file with your default system browser. This command is intended for opening files with external programs that are registered in the "gnuserv-program-alist" variable, which may not include your default system browser.

To open a file with your default system browser, you can use the "helm-find-files-action" command, which allows you to run a custom action on the selected file. This command is bound to "C-c C-x" by default, which is the same shortcut that you used for the "helm-ff-run-open-file-externally" command.

To use the "helm-find-files-action" command, you first need to select the file you want to open with helm-find-files, and then press "C-c C-x" to open the action menu. From the menu, select the "Browse Url" action, which will open the selected file with your default system browser.